# Update 200 tables in database

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two databases with a couple hundred tables in them each, in SQL Server.  The tables in the two databases are 90% the same, with about 20 different tables in each. I'm working on a stored procedure to update database2 with the data from the tables it shares in database1.

I‌'m thinking truncate the tables and then insert the records from the tables in the other database like:

```
t‌runcate table database2.dbo.table2

s‌elect * 
into data‌‌‌base2.dbo.table2 
from database1.dbo.table1
```

I‌s this the best way to do this, and is there a better way to do it than writing a couple hundred of these statements?‌

Comment: You probably should use `Information_Schema.Tables` and `Information_Schema.Columns` on both database to verify that columns, data types, match, and that you don't have identity keys. Then you could construct your queries for tables that matched as dynamic sql and run that.

Comment: Yes there is better way. You should use SSIS(Integration Services package) packages which provides lot of support for doing these kind of bulk operations. Bit tedious but it will be good way to do what you want.

Comment: Note that `truncate table` does not work when there are `foreign key` in the table

Comment: Yes, there are a couple of better ways. SSIS as mentioned by Coder of Code, or,  if the databases needs to stay in sync, use replication.

Comment: Redgate software does this really awesome and easy, had chance to use it couple of times ... but not sure if you can get a trial version to finish the job

Answer (score 1):

This may give an error because the table already exists in Database(As per your truncate command). Given query will create a new table.

"s‌elect * 
into data‌‌‌base2.dbo.table2 ---Create new table 
from database1.dbo.table1"
 If you want the same table structure and Data then you should generate scripts for Schema and data and run that scripts on another database(DB2)

1. right click the database and select tasks --> generate scripts
2. Next --> select the requested table/tables (select required tables)
3. next --> click advanced --> types of data to script = schema and data
   also, change check for Existence--True
4. next and finish